# PHP array_intersect + array_flip with array that has values multiple times

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect, array-flip

I have two arrays:

```
$arr1 = array(101 => 250, 102 => 250, 103 => 250, 104 => 500, 105 => 500, 106 => 500,);
```

and

```
$arr2 = array(0 => 103, 1 => 104, 2 => 105)
```

**The result I want to get is**

```
Array (103 => 250, 104 => 500)
```

---

I have tried working with

```
array_intersect(array_flip($arr1), $arr2);
```

but

```
array_flip($arr1)
```

gives something like

```
Array(103 => 250, 106 => 500)
```

thus, keys get lost and can not be intersected correctly. Is there a way to get the desired result?

Comment: not unexpected that keys get lost - array_flip swaps keys and values, and since you have "duplicate" values, you will lose some keys. and you can use `array_intersect_keys()` instead, which uses keys instead of values for the intersection comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does the job. I hope it is self-explanatory.

```
array_unique(array_intersect_key($arr1, array_flip($arr2)))
```

Comment: perfect! I just needed to use the array_flip on the other array and then use array_intersect_key. Of cause! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard php library functions for this might reduce the readability of the code. I would go with an explicit `foreach` loop that goes over `$arr2`.

```
$ans = array();

foreach($arr2 as $key) {
    if (isset($arr1[$key]) && !in_array($arr1[$key], $ans)) {
        $ans[$key] = $arr1[$key];
    }
}
```

This function should O(n*n) where n is the length of `$arr2`.